# Convergence of Compact Linear Opeators in $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $A_n: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ be

$(A_nf)(x)= \int_0^1 sin(n\pi(x-y))f(y)dy$.

Are they compact operators? Is there any kind of convergence?

They are continous since $\|A_nf\| \leq \|f\| $. They are compact since the kernel $sin(n(x-y)) \in L^2([0,1]\times[0,1])$. Probably there is weak convergence of $A_n \rightharpoonup 0$ because $\sin(n(x-y)) \rightharpoonup 0$ (If I don't go wrong). I don't know how to explain that there is no strong convergence to a compact operator.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) What are your integration bounds ? 2) Are you sure it's not $(A_nf)(x)= \int sin(\pi n(x-y))f(y)dy$ with a $\pi$ factor ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks I edited. There is no $\pi$ here but I can trust we need a $\pi$, I added it!